# File Encryption (EFS method)

Tags: encryption, hash, aes, protocol-design, file-encryption

I'm implementing (for learning purposes) a file encryptor, which uses the following method (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System). I have 3 kinds of keys: RSA public/private, AES, and a user key derived from a phrase.

- encrypt the file with AES (I use OFB mode).
- encrypt the AES key with RSA.
- write the encrypted AES key to the file header
- generate a user key
- with the user key I encrypt the RSA private key and the IV too, then place them in a database file.
- I also hash the original AES key and store it in the database

A database file structure looks like this:

```
size_t fileID;
byte rsaPrivateEncrypted[RSA_KEY_LEN];
byte aesIVEncrypted[AES_BLOCK_LEN];
byte aesKeyHash[HASH_LEN];
```

The key hash is used to validate the key, before decrypting the file check if the hashes are the same.

I've just read that there is still no implementation of a key wrap algorithm in the Crypto++ library, so I use the method:

- hash a user-defined string (phrase) with MD5 (128 bit) - this will be the KEK
- hash the hash again with MD5, this is the IV for KEK
- encrypt the RSA private key and AES IV with them using AES

I've chosen MD5 because its length fits AES's key/block size. (I know I could use the first n-bit of a longer hash too).
I assume this way is pretty insecure since I've read that there are special algorithms for this purpose (AESKW). What are the main drawbacks of this implementation? How can I make the key wrap/generation method more secure?

Also, in the wiki article, there is one more key:

- FEK - KEK(RSA) - **DPAPI** - USER (hashed from PW).

What's the purpose of this key? As far as I understand, it is only used to decrypt the KEK. But the USER key could do this, since it is as secure as the USER key, no?

Comment: DPAPI has several purposes in Windows besides encrypting the RSA private key (to encrypt other secrets like WiFi passwords, and IE account passwords etc.); moreover the hash from the password is used only after thousands of iterations (and a random salt) provided by the DPAPI API. This slows down direct cracking attacks on the encrypted secret key, if the NTHash is not available, e.g.

Comment: And, as an afterthought, DPAPI has a mechanism to avoid re-encryption of secrets (like RSA private keys) protected by it, when a user changes its password. This is an added benefit.